# android GCM service (production key vs development key)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I know with iOS you need to generate a different key for the different environments.  Is this the same for android with google cloud messaging?

I'm about ready to launch my app and just need to know if I need to update my key to a "production" key vs the key I've been developing and testing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't. In gcm you only need the Api id from api console. In your api console its called Project Number.